# What kind of output is this?

Tags: cable, monitors

I would like to connect my computer to my HDMI-enabled monitor. The computer has a VGA out and one of these:

[image: Image of computer video output port]

I don't know what that is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort) socket. Display port to HDMI adaptors are available, almost always DisplayPort is set up as displayport dual-mode, meaning a simple, cheap cable adaptor—e.g. this randomly selected two dollar jobbie from ebay —will suffice for connecting it to HDMI equipment.

[image: ebay ad for dp to hdmi adaptor]